# Possible to use field in ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a `DateTime` in my `at` field and a number of minutes duration in my `minutes` field. I want to get all the records where the current time falls within `at` and `at + minutes`. Something like:

```
SpecialEvent.where(at: (DateTime.now - 120.minutes)..DateTime.now)
```

Except I'm guessing the `120.minutes` duration. The exact number of minutes duration for each `SpecialEvent` is in a `minutes` field. But I don't know how to use that `minutes` field within the query...

Answer (score 1):

Some databases (including MySQL) support functions in SQL to perform calculations with dates. This is required to efficiently calculate the timestamp based on data inside the database. Thus, you need to generate correct SQL for your specific database flavour. The example below should work for MySQL. If you use another database, you probably need to adapt this to the available date functions.

```
SpecialEvent.where(['at >= :now - INTERVAL minutes MINUTE AND at <= :now', now: DateTime.now])
```

This effectively generates the following SQL query (although with a literal date value instead of `NOW()`:

```
SELECT * FROM special_events WHERE at >= NOW() - INTERVAL minutes MINUTE AND at <= NOW();
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL... I'll figure out how to do this in PostgreSQL. Curious, why enclose the where condition in square brackets?

Comment: PostgreSQL has a similar mechanism. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work with the `minutes` field. It will only work if I have a hardcoded number in there like `INTERVAL '30 MINUTES'`.

Answer (score -2):

You can format your query like:
        `SpecialEvent.where(at: (DateTime.now - 120.minutes)..DateTime.now, minutes: '<your search value>')`